# Add a spring profile to the existing ones in a SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBootTest and I want to add a spring-profile to the existing ones for a specific tests. I tried `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, properties = "spring.profiles.include=my-second-profile")` which was suggested in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7668 but this doesn't work at all. Only the profile which was included is active now. As a result my context does not start because required properties from the default active profiles are missing. Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Where/how are your active profiles defined?

Answer (score 0):

`properties` expects an array `String[]` not a single object `String`.

`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"spring.profiles.include=my-second-profile"})`

Surround your String with `{}` and it should work.

Comment: AFAIK, ie for all other annotations I've used, when there's only one element in the array, it's OK to leave out the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that works for me is using the separate `@ActiveProfiles` annotation, and not necessarily use the `properties` as you do. `@ActiveProfiles` expects a comma-separated string of profile names. So your annotations could become as follows:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "main-profile,my-second-profile,other-profile")
```

Comment: The problem is that the same test is running on stage-workstation (local development) and stage-ci (jenkins) and for stage-ci which is activated when the test is running on jenkins I need a proxy which is configured through the stage-ci profile. With your approach the profiles would be static .. But thanks for you answere!